# JSOUP URL with spaces - %20 is taken away

Tags: java, url, jsoup, spaces

I want to read the following URL:

> *https://www.fangraphs.com/liveboxscore.aspx?date=2018-03-29&team=Blue Jays&dh=0&season=2018*

Problem: There is space between Blue and Jays

When connecting and retrieving data via JSOUP (jsoup.connect(url).get()) I retrieve the following error:

> **HTTP error fetching URL. Status=400, URL=https://www.fangraphs.com/boxscore.aspx?date=2018-03-29&team=Blue
>   Jays&dh=0&season=2018**

Even when replacing the space with %20 or using encode, the issue still persists.

Any clue what I need to do?

Thanks

Comment: Has anyone an idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

remove the url spaces beforeJSOUP.connect(URL)

```
try {
                url = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(url, "UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it did not solve the problem - I updated the description above with examples to be more precise